# How to change an attribute value in a validation form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have created a validation form, this is one of the fields that you have to compile:

```
<input type="number" name="height" min="160" max="200"/>
```

but, I want to modify the minimum number if someone clicks on a radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
```

if someone clicks here I want to set the minimum number of the height to `170`

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
```

if someone clicks here I want to set the minimum number of the height to `160`

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: are you able to use a library such as jQuery? or do you need to use javascript only?

Comment: have you written any javascript code to achieve the required behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input id='height_input' type="number" name="height" min="160" max="200"/>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" onclick="setmin(170)">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" onclick="setmin(160)">
```

Then in Javascript:

```
function setmin(n) {
    document.getElementById('height_input').min = n;
}
```

jQuery is totally unnecessary. No need to use a huge library for such a simple task. Remember to **add** the id='height_input' to your first input like I show above.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would be your best bet.

you can change the value of attributes using [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), and you can add click handlers to the two radio buttons using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Here's a good resource for [getting started with jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery? JavaScript itself is simple enough, and you want to import a whole library for this simple functionality.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you need this sort of thing once, you'll probably run into other situations where it will be needed.  Native DOM manipulation has tons of caveats, and I avoid it when at all possible. jQuery is the best tool for the job.  EDIT* That being said, it's just a preference.